# Obtener una variable del método de una clase POO en PDO PHP

Tags: php, poo, pdo

tengo una clase con un método que me crea un paginador.
Necesito, desde otro archivo instanciar la clase y obtener la variable $paGinas

```
         class Proyectos {    

              public static function consultaProyectos(){  
               $pagina = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
               $porPagina = isset($_GET['por-pagina']) && $_GET['por-pagina'] <= 50 ? (int)$_GET['por-pagina'] : 5;
               $inicio = ($pagina > 1) ? ($pagina * $porPagina) - $porPagina : 0;

               $conexion = new conexion();//objeto conexion
               $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM " . self::TABLA . " 
                       ORDER BY nombre_proyecto ASC 
                       LIMIT {$inicio},{$porPagina}");//uso la constante TABLA
               $consulta->execute();
               $registros = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

               $total = $conexion->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->fetch()['total'];
               $paGinas = ceil($total / $porPagina);

               return $registros;
              }
          }
```

instancio la clase y el método de esta manera, pero no me llega la variable $paGina

```
            $bucle_proyectos = Proyectos::consultaProyectos();


            //convierto el contenido del bucle en una variable que llamar en el template de smarty
            foreach($bucle_proyectos as $item):
                  $bucleProyectos.= '<li><a href="proyecto_detalle.php?id='.$item['id'].'">'.$item['nombre_proyecto'].'</a> - <a href="proyecto_update.php?id='.$item['id'].'">editar</a></li>';
            endforeach;


            for($x = 1;$x <= $paGinas;$x++):
              $paginador.= $x;
            endfor;
```

Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia? Gracias!

Comment: Se me ocurre que $registros fuese una estructura que te retorne los datos completos de la paginación con las variables páginas, total, porPagina y los datos obviamente, así puedes acceder a ellas desde cualquier lugar en que llames a tu método estático. Podría colocar el código pero desde el móvil es complicado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, `$paGina` es **local** a tu función estática `consultaProyectos( )`. Para *sacarla* de ahí, puedes simplemente devolverla:

```
return [ $registros, $paGina ];
```

y luego, pues la usas accediendo al *array*:

```
$resultado = Proyectos::consultaProyectos();
$bucle_proyectos = $resultado[0]

foreach($bucle_proyectos as $item):
  $bucleProyectos.= '<li><a href="proyecto_detalle.php?id='.$item['id'].'">'.$item['nombre_proyecto'].'</a> - <a href="proyecto_update.php?id='.$item['id'].'">editar</a></li>';
endforeach;

for($x = 1;$x <= $resultado[1];$x++):
  $paginador.= $x;
endfor;
```

Comment: Buena solución, funciona perfecto. Pasarlo como un Array, todas las respuestas han coincidido. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre que dentro de tu clase declares un array asociativo `clave => valor` donde englobes todas las variables que deseas mandar para posteriormente utilziarlas en el otro archivo; te construyo un ejemplo que pudieras adaptar.

A lo que me refiero, en tu método estas tratando de devolver múltiples valores pero solo colocas `return _$registro` es decir la variable `$paginas` se queda dentro del scope de `consultaProyectos` por lo cual necesitas construir un modo de retornar mas de un valor a la vez, por lo cual hacer lo siguiente te puede resultar útil

**Archivo1.php**

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public static function saluda()
    {
        $nombre = "Alfredo";
        $edad = 23;
        return array("nombre" => $nombre, "edad" => $edad);
    }
}
```

**Ya dentro del Archivo2.php**

```
require "Archivo1.php";

$datos = Person::saluda();

foreach($datos as $dato)
{
    echo $dato;
}
```

Como puedes observar le hago un  `return` al array asociativo donde coloqué las 2 variables que necesito mandar al Archivo2.php para que de esta manera el método saluda() me los retorne y pueda usarlos después.

Como me llega un array, necesito descomponerlo para poder leer sus valores internos, lo cual lo logro con un foreach

Lo cual al final me debería retornar en pantalla esto

```
Alfredo  23
```

Dentro de tu método lo único que deberías agregar es esto

```
array("registros" => $registros, "paGinas" => $paGinas);
```